# Populate context in unit test for webclient

Tags: spring, spring-webflux, project-reactor

I have added a WebClientCustomizer that gets a value from the context view that will be added as a header for the outgoing request. The code looks like this:

```
@Override
public void customize(WebClient.Builder builder) {
    builder
        .filter((request, next) ->
                Mono.deferContextual(contextView ->
                    next.exchange(from(request)
                        .header("myHeader", contextView.getOrDefault("id", UUID.randomUUID().toString())).build()
                    )
        ));
}
```

I want to create a test for this where the contextView contains a pre-defined value. I am able to use MockWebServer to receive the request, which I can then read the header from. But the question is, how do I populate the reactor context in the test?

Comment: How do you populate context in the application?

Comment: With a WebFilter: `return chain.filter(exchange).contextWrite(context -> context.put("id", id));`

Comment: I mean where are you getting this id? Basically you would need to simulate the same in test.

Comment: The incoming request

Comment: It must be possible to add a dummy value to the context, somehow? So I could test this component in isolation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use several approaches to validate this logic.

1. Test `WebClient` in isolation by providing context explicitly.

```
@Test
void test() {
    request() // webclient call
      .contextWrite(context -> context.put("id", "00000"))
      .as(StepVerifier::create)
      .assertNext(res -> {
        // assert results
      })
      .verifyComplete();
}
```

2. In addition, you can use `WebTestClient` to validate the flow e2e by sending request to controller.

Comment: Works perfectly to do the contextWrite after I have the mono from WebClient. Thanks!